# Netrw how to hide line?

Tags: netrw

My Netrw config here.

```
let g:netrw_banner = 0
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_altv = 1
let g:netrw_winsize = 25
```

Just i want to hide "|" and "/". But how?
I try `:help netrw` command but i can't found solution.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's no documented way to hide the slashes that follow directory names. If you're willing to change a bit of code to remove them then find the following line in `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/netrw.vim`

```
let pfile= filename."/"
```

You can just search for "getftype" to get you in the general area of the (large) file...the line above is within a few lines of the last occurrence of that string.

Now just remove the `/` (leave the surrounding quotes) and save the change. That should do it. The next time you launch an instance of `vim` no more slashes.

As for the vertical lines, they are integral to tree-style listings which is what you are using. The listings would be difficult to read without them so it's no surprise that there's no way to disable them. You *could* use a different list style...

Change `g:netrw_liststyle` to 0, 1 or 2.

From `:h netrw-browser-settings`:

```
  *g:netrw_liststyle*       Set the default listing style:
                                = 0: thin listing (one file per line)
                                = 1: long listing (one file per line with time
                                     stamp information and file size)
                                = 2: wide listing (multiple files in columns)
                                = 3: tree style listing
```

Comment: You could also change the highlighting group `netrwClassify` to make the slashes less visible.